# Doctrine: custom entity repository

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm, repository-pattern

Have some problems with building custom entity repository.

I have the following fatal error while trying method of custom entity repository

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Undefined method 'getByParentId'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!' in C:\Users\user\Desktop\projects\interview\application\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository.php:215 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\user\Desktop\projects\interview\application\controllers\CommentController.php(58): Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository->__call('getByParentId', Array) #1 C:\Users\user\Desktop\projects\interview\application\controllers\CommentController.php(58): Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository->getByParentId('1') #2 [internal function]: CommentController->viewCommentsListByParentId('1') #3 C:\Users\user\Desktop\projects\interview\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #4 C:\Users\user\Desktop\projects\interview\index.php(203): require_once('C:\Users\user\D...') #5 {main} thrown in C:\Users\user\Desktop\projects\interview\application\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository.php on line 215
```

My project structure is
models
  Mappings
  Repositories
  Entities
  Proxies

My doctrine.php has repository loader like this

```
// load the repositories
$repositoryClassLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Repositories', APPPATH.'models');
$repositoryClassLoader->register();
```

My model class has the following declaration

```
namespace Entities;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Entities\Comment
 * @Entity (repositoryClass="Repositories\CommentRepository")
 */
class Comment
{
```

My Repository class has the following declaration

```
namespace Repositories;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Entities;

class CommentRepository extends EntityRepository {
    public function getByParentId($parentid) {
        return parent::findBy(array('parentid' => $parentid), array('creationdate' => 'DESC'));
    }
}
```

Controller code calling for methods of custom repository

```
   public function viewCommentsListByParentId($parentid) {
        $data = array();
        $data ['comment'] = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\Comment')->getByParentId($parentid);

        $this->load->view('commentsList', $data);
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong??? Please, help.

---

```
object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata)#34 (32) {
    ["name"]=> string(16) "Entities\Comment"
    ["namespace"]=> string(8) "Entities"
    ["rootEntityName"]=> string(16) "Entities\Comment"
    ["customRepositoryClassName"]=> NULL
    ["isMappedSuperclass"]=> bool(false)
    ["parentClasses"]=> array(0) { }
    ["subClasses"]=> array(0) { }
    ["namedQueries"]=> array(0) { }
    ["identifier"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(2) "id"
    }
    ["inheritanceType"]=> int(1)
    ["generatorType"]=> int(4)
    ["fieldMappings"]=> array(11) {
        ["id"]=> array(4) {
            ["fieldName"]=> string(2) "id"
            ["type"]=> string(7) "integer"
            ["id"]=> bool(true)
            ["columnName"]=> string(2) "id"
        }
        ["parentid"]=> array(4) {
            ["fieldName"]=> string(8) "parentid"
            ["type"]=> string(7) "integer"
            ["columnName"]=> string(8) "parentid"
            ["nullable"]=> bool(false)
        }
        ["isactive"]=> array(4) {
            ["fieldName"]=> string(8) "isactive"
            ["type"]=> string(7) "integer"
            ["columnName"]=> string(8) "isactive"
            ["nullable"]=> bool(false)
        }
        ["isremoved"]=> array(4) {
            ["fieldName"]=> string(9) "isremoved"
            ["type"]=> string(7) "integer"
            ["columnName"]=> string(9) "isremoved"
            ["nullable"]=> bool(false)
        }
        ["removaldate"]=> array(4) {
            ["fieldName"]=> string(11) "removaldate"
            ["type"]=> string(8) "datetime"
            ["columnName"]=> string(11) "removaldate"
            ["nullable"]=> bool(true)
        }
        ["user_name"]=> array(5) {
            ["fieldName"]=> string(9) "user_name"
            ["type"]=> string(6) "string"
            ["columnName"]=> string(9) "user_name"
            ["length"]=> int(255)
            ["nullable"]=> bool(false)
        }
        ["user_email"]=> array(5) {
            ["fieldName"]=> string(10) "user_email"
            ["type"]=> string(6) "string"
            ["columnName"]=> string(10) "user_email"
            ["length"]=> int(255)
            ["nullable"]=> bool(false)
        }
        ["user_avatar"]=> array(5) {
            ["fieldName"]=> string(11) "user_avatar"
            ["type"]=> string(6) "string"
            ["columnName"]=> string(11) "user_avatar"
            ["length"]=> int(255)
            ["nullable"]=> bool(false)
        }
        ["comment"]=> array(4) {
            ["fieldName"]=> string(7) "comment"
            ["type"]=> string(4) "text"
            ["columnName"]=> string(7) "comment"
            ["nullable"]=> bool(false)
        }
        ["creationdate"]=> array(4) {
            ["fieldName"]=> string(12) "creationdate"
            ["type"]=> string(8) "datetime"
            ["columnName"]=> string(12) "creationdate"
            ["nullable"]=> bool(false)
        }
        ["rating"]=> array(4) {
            ["fieldName"]=> string(6) "rating"
            ["type"]=> string(7) "integer"
            ["nullable"]=> bool(false)
            ["columnName"]=> string(6) "rating"
        }
    }
    ["fieldNames"]=> array(11) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "id"
        ["parentid"]=> string(8) "parentid"
        ["isactive"]=> string(8) "isactive"
        ["isremoved"]=> string(9) "isremoved"
        ["removaldate"]=> string(11) "removaldate"
        ["user_name"]=> string(9) "user_name"
        ["user_email"]=> string(10) "user_email"
        ["user_avatar"]=> string(11) "user_avatar"
        ["comment"]=> string(7) "comment"
        ["creationdate"]=> string(12) "creationdate"
        ["rating"]=> string(6) "rating"
    }
    ["columnNames"]=> array(11) {
        ["id"]=> string(2) "id"
        ["parentid"]=> string(8) "parentid"
        ["isactive"]=> string(8) "isactive"
        ["isremoved"]=> string(9) "isremoved"
        ["removaldate"]=> string(11) "removaldate"
        ["user_name"]=> string(9) "user_name"
        ["user_email"]=> string(10) "user_email"
        ["user_avatar"]=> string(11) "user_avatar"
        ["comment"]=> string(7) "comment"
        ["creationdate"]=> string(12) "creationdate"
        ["rating"]=> string(6) "rating"
    }
    ["discriminatorValue"]=> NULL
    ["discriminatorMap"]=> array(0) { }
    ["discriminatorColumn"]=> NULL
    ["table"]=> array(1) {
        ["name"]=> string(7) "Comment"
    }
    ["lifecycleCallbacks"]=> array(0) { }
    ["associationMappings"]=> array(0) { }
    ["isIdentifierComposite"]=> bool(false)
    ["containsForeignIdentifier"]=> bool(false)
    ["idGenerator"]=> object(Doctrine\ORM\Id\IdentityGenerator)#40 (1) {
        ["_seqName":"Doctrine\ORM\Id\IdentityGenerator":private]=> NULL
    }
    ["sequenceGeneratorDefinition"]=> NULL
    ["tableGeneratorDefinition"]=> NULL
    ["changeTrackingPolicy"]=> int(1)
    ["isVersioned"]=> NULL
    ["versionField"]=> NULL
    ["reflClass"]=> object(ReflectionClass)#41 (1) {
        ["name"]=> string(16) "Entities\Comment"
    }
    ["isReadOnly"]=> bool(false)
    ["reflFields"]=> array(11) {
        ["id"]=> object(ReflectionProperty)#35 (2) {
            ["name"]=> string(2) "id"
            ["class"]=> string(16) "Entities\Comment"
        }
        ["parentid"]=> object(ReflectionProperty)#42 (2) {
            ["name"]=> string(8) "parentid"
            ["class"]=> string(16) "Entities\Comment"
        }
        ["isactive"]=> object(ReflectionProperty)#43 (2) {
            ["name"]=> string(8) "isactive"
            ["class"]=> string(16) "Entities\Comment"
        }
        ["isremoved"]=> object(ReflectionProperty)#44 (2) {
            ["name"]=> string(9) "isremoved" 
            ["class"]=> string(16) "Entities\Comment" 
        } 
        ["removaldate"]=> object(ReflectionProperty)#45 (2) { 
            ["name"]=> string(11) "removaldate" 
            ["class"]=> string(16) "Entities\Comment" 
        } 
        ["user_name"]=> object(ReflectionProperty)#46 (2) { 
            ["name"]=> string(9) "user_name" 
            ["class"]=> string(16) "Entities\Comment" 
        } 
        ["user_email"]=> object(ReflectionProperty)#47 (2) { 
            ["name"]=> string(10) "user_email" 
            ["class"]=> string(16) "Entities\Comment" 
        } 
        ["user_avatar"]=> object(ReflectionProperty)#48 (2) { 
            ["name"]=> string(11) "user_avatar" 
            ["class"]=> string(16) "Entities\Comment" 
        } 
        ["comment"]=> object(ReflectionProperty)#49 (2) { 
            ["name"]=> string(7) "comment" 
            ["class"]=> string(16) "Entities\Comment" 
        } 
        ["creationdate"]=> object(ReflectionProperty)#50 (2) { 
            ["name"]=> string(12) "creationdate" 
            ["class"]=> string(16) "Entities\Comment" 
        } 
        ["rating"]=> object(ReflectionProperty)#51 (2) { 
            ["name"]=> string(6) "rating" 
            ["class"]=> string(16) "Entities\Comment" 
        } 
    } 
    ["_prototype":"Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo":private]=> NULL 
}
```

Comment: Do you have any metadata cache active? If so, purge it. I'm not 100% sure if this is cached, but it is part of the class metadata.

Comment: I use apc cache for production. Of course i tried to clear cache. the same result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have imported Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM.

So you should use `@ORM\Entity` instead of `@Entity` in Comment class annotation.

Because for now it does not load annotation `["customRepositoryClassName"]=> NULL`

```
 /**
  * Entities\Comment
  * @ORM\Entity (repositoryClass="Repositories\CommentRepository")
  */
 class Comment
 {
 ..
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```php
/**
 * Entities\Comment
 * @Entity (repositoryClass="Repositories\CommentRepository")
 */
class Comment
{
```

There's one space between `@Entity` and the parameters for that annotation: remove it.

Comment: I removed. The same result

Comment: Can you dump the class metadata for `Entities\Comment`? `$em->getClassMetadata('Entities\Comment');`

Comment: @Grace please make a gist/pastebin of it instead (clean it up first, so at least it's readable)

Comment: How can i do that? I don't understand what u want of me

Comment: In your metadata is `["customRepositoryClassName"]=> NULL`, so clearly it is eighter caching or the annotation is not parsed correctly. Your annotation looks correct if you remove the space as Ocramius suggested. Place a breakpoint or put some debugging code in the [AnnotationDriver](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php) at line 78 to see what happens.

Comment: Have you update your schema ? it updates the cache and so your annotation is OK.

Comment: Thank you everybody for help. I solved problem by defining entity on yaml mapping file and auto generating entity classes, proxies and custom repositories too.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the OP posting their answer in the comments.

When I attempted to call any of doctrine's clear-cache commands it threw an exception.

`$ vendor/bin/doctrine orm:clear-cache:metadata Cannot clear APC Cache from Console, its shared in the Webserver memory and not accessible from the CLI.`.

My development environment does not use APC so the repository was running fine. When I uploaded it to the production server, it failed with the same error as the OP.

I was able to resolve this issue by executing `apc_clear_cache()` from a web page. Afterward the custom repository loaded fine.

EG:
http://mydoamin.com/clear-cache.php

```
<?php

apc_clear_cache();
```

Running it in the CLI will only clear the CLI cache and not the webserver's cache.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-clear-cache.php